# Is an invariant or reducing subspace necessarily the image of a spectral projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

In the following, the section numbers I mention are from Rudin's Functional Analysis text,
Chapter 12.

Let $T$ be a bounded normal operator in the (not necessarily separable) Hilbert space $\mathfrak{H}$.
Let $E$ be the resolution of the identity for $T$ on the Borel subsets of the spectrum $\sigma(T)$.
Let $f$ be
a bounded measurable complex function on $\sigma(T)$. Suppose $\mathfrak{M}$ is a closed subspace of
$\mathfrak{H}$ which is reducing for $T$. That is, $T\mathfrak{M}\subseteq\mathfrak{M}$ and
$T^*\mathfrak{M}\subseteq\mathfrak{M}$, or equivalently, $T\mathfrak{M}\subseteq\mathfrak{M}$ and
$T\mathfrak{M}^\perp\subseteq\mathfrak{M}^\perp$. I would like to show that $f(T)\mathfrak{M}\subseteq\mathfrak{M}$, that is, that $\mathfrak{M}$ is an invariant
subspace with respect to $f(T)$.

If I could show that there is a borel subset $\omega\subseteq\sigma(T)$ such that the range
$\mathscr{R}(E(\omega))=\mathfrak{M}$ (that is, $E(\omega)$ is a projection on $\mathfrak{M}$), then
I would be done, because by the spectral theorem (12.23), every $E(\omega')$ commutes with $T$, and by the properties of the resolution of the identity (12.17(c)), $E(\omega)$ commutes with every
$E(\omega')$, so by 12.21, $E(\omega)$ commutes with $f(T)$. I could then write
for $x\in\mathfrak{M}=\mathscr{R}(E(\omega))$, say $x=E(\omega)y$,
$$f(T)x=f(T)E(\omega)y=E(\omega)f(T)y\in\mathscr{R}(E(\omega))=\mathfrak{M}.$$

So, is it true that such an $\omega$ must exist and how do I show it? If not, is it still true that
$\mathfrak{M}$ is $f(T)$-invariant, and how would I show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true in general that the orthogonal projection $P$ onto a reducing subspace $M$ is of the form $P = 1_\omega (T)$ for some subset $\omega$. Indeed, if $T$ is the identity operator, then every subspace is reducing, but the only spectral projections are the trivial projections.

Nevertheless, you have $T P= PT$ (why?), so that Theorem 12.24 in Rudin's functional analysis shows $f(T)P = Pf(T)$, which implies that $f(T)M \subset M$.

Comment: Very good! I'm grateful! If $x\in\mathfrak{H}$ then $x=x_1+x_2$ where $x_1\in\mathfrak{M}$ and $x_2\in\mathfrak{M}^\perp$. Then $Tx_1\in\mathfrak{M}$ and $Tx_2\in\mathfrak{M}^\perp$ so $PTx=PTx_1+PTx_2=Tx_1=TPx$.